# using foreach to add spaces in a 2D array

Tags: c#

I want the produced code to have an additional spacing after every * but using a foreach method but I'm not sure I did it properly I have

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
  char [,] city = new char [10,10];
  int rowLength = city.GetLength(0);
  int colLength = city.GetLength(1);
  string output = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < colLength; j++){
      city[i,j] = '*';
      
      foreach (char val in city)
      output+= val+"\t";
      
      Console.Write("{0}",city[i,j]);
    }//end j
    Console.WriteLine();
  }//end i
  Console.WriteLine("done");
}
}
```

but printed it doesnt add a tab afterwards. Is the placement wrong?

Comment: use to for loops for the same. in place of `foreach `.. and if you already know each item is `*` and know the array dimension. then you can directly set the `output` variable.

Comment: Get your rubber ducky out and read your code out loud. For every row position and for every column pos, you put an asterisk character into your 2 dimensional `city` array AND you walk through the entire `city` array (some elements of which are initialized, some aren't), and append each element and a tab to `output`. When you are finished, you forget about `output`. I _think_ what you want is to finish the row & column for loops after you initialize `city[i,j]`. Then, with `city` initialized, start a second set for row & column for loops to output the contents of `$"{city[i,j]}\t"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So I am not sure this is the exact solution you are looking for, but you can skip the foreach loop, and simply add it to your Write().*

```
        class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                char[,] city = new char[10, 10];
                int rowLength = city.GetLength(0);
                int colLength = city.GetLength(1);
                string output = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
                    {
                        city[i, j] = '*';
        
                        //foreach (char val in city)
                            //output += val + "\t";
        
                        Console.Write("{0}", city[i, j] + "\t");
                    }//end j
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }//end i
                Console.WriteLine("done");
            }
        }
```